# Sort Array of Dictionaries by NSDate as inner key

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort the following array by dates. I tried several methods but didn't work. Here the date string is an inner key of the dictionary.

Array is like this

```
{
    message =         {
        "created_at" = "2015-07-23T07:18:42.315Z";
        "created_at_time_ago" = 3ds;
        direction = sent;
    };
},
    {
    message =         {
        "created_at" = "2015-07-21T02:58:23.461Z";
        "created_at_time_ago" = 5ds;
        direction = sent;
    };
},
    {
    message =         {
        "created_at" = "2015-07-19T13:32:22.111Z";
        "created_at_time_ago" = 7ds;
        direction = sent;
    };
},
```

I tries this code, but didn't work

```
#define KLongDateFormat @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"


NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtDate setDateFormat:KLongDateFormat];
NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
{
    NSDate *date1 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string1];
    NSDate *date2 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string2];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
};
NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:NO comparator:compareDates];
[arrSavedFeeds sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc1]];
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort an array of dictionary of dictionary by inner key using `NSSortDescriptor`. Why don't you just use [`sortUsingComparator(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:) method of NSMutableArray and compare dictionaries instead?

```
NSComparator compareDates = ^(id dict1, id dict2)
{
    NSDate *date1 = [fmtDate dateFromString:[[dict1 valueForKey:@"message"] valueForKey:@"created"]];
    NSDate *date2 = [fmtDate dateFromString:[[dict2 valueForKey:@"message"] valueForKey:@"created"]];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
};

[arrSavedFeeds sortUsingComparator:compareDates];
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you are using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in which case you can save yourself some computation as it can be sorted lexicographically (for positive years).

In which case you can use the following sort descriptor

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"message.created_at" ascending:NO]
```